# Random unrecoverable hard crashes on Ubuntu 16.04, kern.log corrupted

Tags: crash, log

I have ubuntu 16.04 installed on a hard drive which ive used on multiple machines, all of which have this crash occur.  The previous machine was a intel i5-4670k and the new machine is running an amd r7 2700x.  The drive I am using is also relatively new.

Although i haven't had the drive running for long on the new machine this crash has occured twice.  When it does the only way to recover is by the restart button.  I known sysrq is working and reisub has no effect on the system when it freezes up.

Here is a log from the last system crash

```
eul  7 08:49:47 proto kernel: [42244.586607] RTW: recv eapol packet
Jul  7 08:49:47 proto kernel: [42244.586758] RTW: send eapol packet
Jul  7 08:49:53 proto kernel: [42250.988359] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp24s0 OUT= MAC=30:9c:23:d3:a6:b1:04:c5:a4:e3:f5:42:08:00 SRC=185.208.209.90 DST=131.128.51.213 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=239 ID=24931 PROTO=TCP SPT=58943 DPT=7141 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Jul  7 08:49:59 proto kernel: [42256.216685] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp24s0 OUT= MAC=30:9c:23:d3:a6:b1:04:c5:a4:e3:f5:42:08:00 SRC=181.214.87.222 DST=131.128.51.213 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=17543 PROTO=TCP SPT=45450 DPT=7018 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Jul  7 08:50:49 proto kernel: [42306.205078] RTW: recv eapol packet
Jul  7 08:50:49 proto kernel: [42306.205423] RTW: send eapol packet
Jul  7 08:50:50 proto kernel: [42307.593691] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp24s0 OUT= MAC=30:9c:23:d3:a6:b1:04:c5:a4:e3:f5:42:08:00 SRC=58.135.198.145 DST=131.128.51.213 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=46 ID=55736 PROTO=TCP SPT=27727 DPT=2323 WINDOW=18543 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Jul  7 08:51:09 proto kernel: [42326.478142] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp24s0 OUT= MAC=30:9c:23:d3:a6:b1:04:c5:a4:e3:f5:42:08:00 SRC=168.1.128.77 DST=131.128.51.252 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=237 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=10978 DPT=8888 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 

\00\00\00\...\00\00\00\
```

The \00 goes on for a few hundred lines

Comment: Seems like you already diagnosed the problem pretty thoroughly: Faulty hard drive. Look up how to run a SMART test on the drive to be certain.

Comment: "I have ubuntu 16.04 installed on a hard drive"  + " which ive used on multiple machines, all of which have this crash occur" = broken hard disk since you can rule out all the hardware from the other machines except for the hard disk.

Comment: Is it possible for it to be an OS error? I've ran disk tests and they keep coming up fine.